# how to copy charts from one sheet to another or set the destination of the chart?

Tags: excel, vba, graph

So how my code works is that it will plot chart based on the X values in column A and the y columns are the alternating columns (Eg:mean graph x values=entirecolumn1, y values = entirecolumn 2,4,6..etc , sigma graph x values = entire column1, y values =entirecolumn 3,5,7..).

All my graphs are plotted on the same worksheets("data") but i find it to be very messy. I tried to copy and paste all my charts into different worksheets namely sigmagraphs and meangraphs but it only copies and paste for the meangraphs portion only(not sure where it went wrong). So what can i do to make sure all my graphs in data copy and paste accordingly to different worksheets or is it possible to just set the destination of the charts from the start to worksheet sigmagraphs and meangraphs?

Anyways i did not include the code for sigmagraphs because the code will be too long but the code is almost the same as meangraphs's code with  Set rngY = rngDB.Columns(3) and different axes.

[image]

```
Sub plotgraphs()

Call meangraph
Call sigmagraph

End Sub

Private Sub meangraph()
    Dim i As Long, c As Long
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim Cht As chart, co As Shape
    Dim rngDB As Range, rngX As Range, rngY As Range
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Data")

    Set rngDB = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Set rngX = rngDB.Columns(1)
    Set rngY = rngDB.Columns(2)

    Do While Application.CountA(rngY) > 0

        Set co = ws.Shapes.AddChart
        Set Cht = co.chart

        With Cht
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            'remove any data which might have been
            '  picked up when adding the chart
            Do While .SeriesCollection.Count > 0
                .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
            Loop
            'add the data
            With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
                .XValues = rngX.Value
                .Values = rngY.Value
            End With
            'formatting...
            With Cht.Axes(xlValue)
                .MinimumScale = 5
                .MaximumScale = 20
                .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00E+00"
            End With
            Cht.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            Cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        End With
          Set rngY = rngY.Offset(0, 2) 'next y values

    Loop




              Dim OutSht As Worksheet
'
   Dim PlaceInRange As Range

    Set OutSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sigmagraphs") '<~~ Output sheet
   Set PlaceInRange = OutSht.Range("B2:J21")        '<~~ Output location
'


'    To place charts at a distance between them
    For Each chart In Sheets("sigmagraphs").ChartObjects
'        OutSht.Paste PlaceInRange
'        Code below changes the range itself to something 20 rows below
        Set PlaceInRange = PlaceInRange.Offset(20, 0)
   Next chart

End Sub
```

Expected output(where graphs are sorted according to worksheet name)

[image]

Comment: Here `Set co = ws.Shapes.AddChart` you tell VBA in which sheet you want to add that chart. So if you do `Set co = Worksheets("sigmagraphs").Shapes.AddChart` you create it in the worksheet `sigmagraphs`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It works, Thanks. Anyways can i ask is there a way to place the graphs such that they are at a distance between them? Because currently the graphs are all cramp in the same spot. Therefore i tried to offset these graphs using Set PlaceInRange = PlaceInRange.Offset(20, 0) but the charts didnt offset...

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i mean i tried to implement this from the code starting from Set OutSht =.. onwards but it doesn't work